# How do you display mongoose data in a pug template

Tags: node.js, mongoose, pug

I am exploring the PUG templates and have an exporess/mongodb/mongoose backend.

The Router for the index page is meant to display 'testimonials' and I have the following 'route':

```
const Testimonial = require('../models/Testimonial');
exports.index = (req, res) => {
  Testimonial.find((err, testimonials) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error: " + err);
    } else {
      res.render('home2', {
        title: 'website',
        testimonials: testimonials,
      });
    }
  });
};
```

If I were to add a 'console.log' statement before the render it would return all the testimonials in the collection, so the data side works.

The Index page includes a 'partial' pug template for the Testimonials with the following:

```
.nk-box.bg-gray-4
  .nk-gap-4
  .row
    .nk-carousel-2(data-autoplay='12000', data-dots='true')
      .nk-carousel-inner
        each testimonial in testimonials
          div
            div
              blockquote.nk-testimonial-3
                .nk-testimonial-photo(style="background-image: url('/images/avatar-man-2.jpg');")
                .nk-testimonial-body
                  em
                    | &quot; testimonial.Description &quot;
                .nk-testimonial-name.h4 testimonial.CreatedBy
                .nk-testimonial-source testimonial.ModifiedDate
  .nk-gap-4
```

The template creates the correct number of Testimonials but the data in each is not being displayed. Instead I get a testimonial with 'testimonial.Description' instead of the actual words, and 'testimonial.CreatedBy' instead of the person's name.

The template is looping through what is being returned by the looks of it, I just cannot display the data.

I'd certainly appreciate any help you guys can provide.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may need to use the `#{}` between variables to interpolate its values with the template

https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html

```
.nk-box.bg-gray-4
  .nk-gap-4
  .row
    .nk-carousel-2(data-autoplay='12000', data-dots='true')
      .nk-carousel-inner
        each testimonial in testimonials
          div
            div
              blockquote.nk-testimonial-3
                .nk-testimonial-photo(style="background-image: url('/images/avatar-man-2.jpg');")
                .nk-testimonial-body
                  em
                    | &quot; #{testimonial.Description} &quot;
                .nk-testimonial-name.h4 #{testimonial.CreatedBy}
                .nk-testimonial-source #{testimonial.ModifiedDate}
  .nk-gap-4
```